# ZSH Plugins are not working on Mac in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, oh-my-zsh

So I have installed `ZSH` using:

`brew install zsh`

and then I have installed `oh my zsh`:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

then I ran `compaudit`, so the plugins load properly:

`compaudit | xargs chmod g-w`

And then I have also installed `powerlevel10k` and went through it's setup:

https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#oh-my-zsh

---

Point is, this setup worked on a linux system (that I access using `ssh` as root user) but not on `Mac M1`, which I am using as normal priviliged user (which shouldn't be an issue).

I could pinpoint the issue that it is probably in `~/.zshrc`.

If I add `docker` to the plugins in `~/.zshrc`, like this:

```bsh
...

plugins=(git docker)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

...
```

Then `docker` autocomplete works. But just by starting the `zsh` shell, the `docker` plugin will not be loaded if `docker` is not added to this list, even though this is what the `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` is supposed to do, loading plugins it's built-in plugins automatically.

I can't understand why it's not working, I am not getting any errors, it just fails silently.

So no plugin is working (syntax highlight, autocomplete), unless I add it to the `plugins`.

Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to debug this, you can restart your shell in verbose xtrace mode by typing `exec zsh -vx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So no plugin is working (syntax highlight, autocomplete), unless I add it to the `plugins`.

Well, yeah, that's how it's *supposed* to work. OMZ only loads those plugins that you add to the `$plugins` array. The only things it loads without instruction are [its libraries](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/lib).

See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh#enabling-plugins

Comment: So it worked on Linux, because it was working already, unrelated to `zsh` and `OMZ`